# Include Impact as record in Users table

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, data-dump

[The new profile pages](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/) has aired with a new statistic, "People reached". This stat may have research value, but it's not provided in the data dumps.

[image]

This would be useful, for example, where:

> Anyone out there willing to do some SO data analytic magic for me? I'm interested in looking for the trend of people reached as a function of rep <sub>— [source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22729549#22729549) by [wnnmaw](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2084656)</sub>

Please add it as a record!